# How to filter a sentence based on list of the allowed words in python?

Tags: python, nlp, stop-words, pos-tagger

I have allow_wd as words that I want to search.

The sentench is an array of the main database.

The output need:

```
Newsentench = ['one three','']
```

Please help

```
    sentench=['one from twooo or three people are here','he is here']
    allow_wd=['one','two','three','four']
```

Comment: Yeah. I did change it. Please help Ravindra

Comment: I've added the answer. Please check and respond if it's working as accepted. If yes, consider accepting the answer.

Comment: Hi Ravindra, I'm also testing with @Kosay Jabre code and comparing which one is the fastest since I have a thousand records to check. I'll get back to you soon. Okay?

Comment: sure thing.  Interested to know which one's faster.

Comment: Ravindra, your query requires over 7 minutes, Kosay Jabre code requires only 21 s. Thanks for being the fastest response though.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your clarification, this should be what you want.

```
sentench=['one from twooo or three people are here','he is here']
allow_wd=['one','two','three','four']

print([" ".join([word for word in s.split(" ") if word in allow_wd]) for s in sentench])
```

returning: `['one three', '']`

Comment: Hi Reto! Thanks for replying. I just edited my question. I hope it gives more clarification.

Answer (score 1):

Using regex boundaries with \b will ensure that two will be strictly matched and won't match twoo.

```
import re

sentench=['one from twooo or three people are here','he is here']
allow_wd=['one','two','three','four']
newsentench = []

for sent in sentench:
    output = []
    for wd in allow_wd:
        if re.findall('\\b' + wd + '\\b',sent):
            output.append(wd)
    newsentench.append(' '.join(word for word in output))

print(newsentench)
```